# Dramione fanfiction on a spell's name, Draco and Hermione create a potion of empathy and find a cure after deciphering an old journal

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, dramione

I want to find a Dramione fanfiction which I think is on a spell's name.

In it Draco and Hermione are paired for potions. They create a potion of empathy link or something like that. They try to find a cure by deciphering the journal of a lady who had the same problem with her and her rival. Draco and Hermione are successful in making that potion. But it is not that effective and realise they have feelings for each other.

A lot about the life of journal lady is told as well. Her story prevents Draco from leaving the dark side and stay with Hermione.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already but just in case, please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), as well as [these ones on fanfic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in. :)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "on a spell's name"? I'd have thought it would be a site for HP fanfictions, but Google doesn't yield anything obvious. Is the fanfic named after a spell or something?